# Печать в обход диалогового окна (веб-формы ASP)

Tags: javascript, печать, asp, vbscript

Имеется веб-приложение на ASP.NET (c#). Для работы на киоске (сенсорном терминале), к терминалу подключен принтер.
Необходимо вызвать печать веб-страницы с приложения без диалогового окна выбора принтера (принтер по умолчанию).

нашла вот такое решение:

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
Now, calling:

<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

VBScript не срабатывает и ругается на метод ExecWB. Я в vbscript не сильна, нужно похожее решение на c# + javascript.

Да и ложку дёгтя в это все добавляет тот факт, что на киоске IE5...
Помогите пожалуйста, разобраться...))

Comment: и где тут у вас ASP.NET? вынесите <object в разметку (уберите document.write)

Comment: asp на веб странице, я ее сюда не стала выносить. ссылка <a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a> находится непосредственно на форме. Выносить пробовала. При нажатии на кнопку проект вылетает на ошибке "метод WB.ExecWB не поддерживается". Делаю вывод что нужно эту часть не на VBScript, а на шарпе реализовывать...

Comment: Вероятно, не IE5, а кое-кто забыл в html-документе поставить doctype.

Comment: нет, доктайп есть. Документ вот так начинается: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Receipt.aspx.cs" Inherits="Receipt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: В сгенерированной странице `<!DOCTYPE` идёт в самом начале без пробелов, пероводов строк и BOM?

Comment: Да, все чисто. Сразу идет <!DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо! Вопрос решен! Пришлось сделать небольшой финт ушами)
Раньше данное веб-приложение на киоске запускалось с помощью HTA-приложения. В этом случае приходилось довольствоваться только способностями дефолтного браузера.

Теперь вместо хта - написано приложение на WindowsForms (c#), в котором лежит компонент WebBrowser и поверх невидимая кнопка "Печать". В компонент подгружается нужная страница, появляется кнопка "Печать" и при нажатии с помощью функции `webBrowser1.Print()` страница сразу улетает на печать на принтер по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

К проекту подключите сборку `Microsoft.mshtml.dll`

```
var wb = new WebBrowser(); 
// ...
var doc = wb.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.execCommand("Print", true, 0);
```

а если надо вызвать из javascript на веб-странице, то так:

```
document.execCommand('print', false);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я правильно понимаю: чтобы мне вызвать на клиенте печать в обход диалога нужно сделать следующее: подключить к проекту сборку Microsoft.mshtml.dll и вызвать обработчике кнопки "Печать" - document.execCommand('print', false);? на серверной части тут ничего дописывать не нужно будет?

Comment: что у вас на клиенте? если прогр на c#, то - да (надо к проекту подключить mshtml), а если веб-страница, то - нет.

Comment: У меня веб-страница

Comment: значит вариант для javascript. в код страницы перед `</body>` добавьте `<script>function print() { document.execCommand('print'); }</script>` и вызовите print() при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: добавила указанный код. Окно выбора принтера все равно появляется

Comment: а если ('print', false) или ('print', true) или ('print', false, null)? а на клиенте .net установлен? или только браузер?

Comment: не один из вариантов, к сожалению, не работает. На клиенте только браузер

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность использовать хром(иум), то:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```
--enable-kiosk-mode --kiosk-printing
```

Comment: спасибо, но только IE и только 5 версия..(

Answer (score 0):

print.js

```
// The code by Captain <cerebrum@iname.com>
// Mead & Company, http://www.meadroid.com/wpm/

// fake print() for IE4.x
if ( !printIsNativeSupport() )
  window.print = printFrame;

// main stuff
function printFrame(frame, onfinish) {
  if ( !frame ) frame = window;

  if ( frame.document.readyState !== "complete" &&
       !confirm("The document to print is not downloaded yet! Continue with printing?") )
  {
    if ( onfinish ) onfinish();
    return;
  }

  if ( printIsNativeSupport() ) {
    /* focus handling for this scope is IE5Beta workaround,
       should be gone with IE5 RTM.
    */
    var focused = document.activeElement; 
    frame.focus();
    frame.self.print();
    if ( onfinish ) onfinish();
    if ( focused && !focused.disabled ) focused.focus();
    return;
  }

  var eventScope = printGetEventScope(frame);
  var focused = document.activeElement;

  window.printHelper = function() {
    execScript("on error resume next: printWB.ExecWB 6, 1", "VBScript");
    printFireEvent(frame, eventScope, "onafterprint");
    printWB.outerHTML = "";
    if ( onfinish ) onfinish();
    if ( focused && !focused.disabled ) focused.focus();
    window.printHelper = null;
  }

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",
    "<object id=\"printWB\" width=0 height=0 \
    classid=\"clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2\"></object>");

  printFireEvent(frame, eventScope, "onbeforeprint");
  frame.focus();
  window.printHelper = printHelper;
  setTimeout("window.printHelper()", 0);
}

// helpers
function printIsNativeSupport() {
  var agent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var i = agent.indexOf("MSIE ")+5;
  return parseInt(agent.substr(i)) >= 5 && agent.indexOf("5.0b1") < 0;
}

function printFireEvent(frame, obj, name) {
  var handler = obj[name];
  switch ( typeof(handler) ) {
    case "string": frame.execScript(handler); break;
    case "function": handler();
  }
}

function printGetEventScope(frame) {
  var frameset = frame.document.all.tags("FRAMESET");
  if ( frameset.length ) return frameset[0];
  return frame.document.body;
}
```

form.asp

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
function Print(){
        with(document.myform)
        {
            target = 'printHiddenFrame';
            action = 'report.asp';
            submit();
            target = '';
            action = '';
        }
}

function onprintHiddenFrame()
{
    if (printHiddenFrame.document.readyState=="complete" && printHiddenFrame.location.href != 'about:blank')
      printFrame(printHiddenFrame);
}
```

```
<iframe name=printHiddenFrame width=0 height=0 onreadystatechange="onprintHiddenFrame()">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Во-первых, это какая-то жуть. А во-вторых, как этот код связан с диалоговым окном?